# How to remove visible background boundary around object after saliency detection?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am working on a background removal problem. I used Deep learning based saliency detection technique to separate foreground and background.

Sample Input - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei4xb.jpg

Result after Background Removal - https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEj4W.jpg

As you can see there is a bluish hue around the footballer. Is there any image processing technique to remove this?

**What I tried?**

I have already tried eroding mask (alpha channel) using `cv.erode` but did not get good results.

Comment: Use a combination of desaturating the background color and anti-aliasing the outline of the alpha channel

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way in Python/OpenCV by desaturating blue, eroding, masking and anti-aliasing.

```
 - Read input unchanged to keep the alpha channel
 - Extract the BGR channels
 - Extract the Alpha channel
 - Erode the alpha channel
 - Create the outline mask where the blue remains
 - Create a blue mask showing where the image is blue
 - Create the logical and of the two masks
 - Desaturate the BGR image
 - Blend the BGR with the desaturated image using the mask
 - Blur the alpha channel
 - Stretch mid-gray or higher to black to antialias the blurred alpha channel
 - Put the antialiased alpha channel into the blended BGR image
 - Save the results
```

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure

# load image with alpha channel
img = cv2.imread('bg_removed.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# extract only bgr channels
bgr = img[:, :, 0:3]

# extract alpha channel
a = img[:, :, 3]

# erode alpha channel
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
ae = cv2.morphologyEx(a, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, kernel)

# compute outline mask as difference
omask = a - ae
omask[omask>0] = 255

# create blue mask
lower=(135,100,0)
upper=(185,160,150)
bmask = cv2.inRange(bgr, lower, upper)

# mask as product of omask and bmask
mask = cv2.bitwise_and(omask, bmask)
imask = 255 - mask

# create desaturated bgr image
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
hsv[:,:,1] = 0
bgrd = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

# blend bgr, bgrd using mask
bgr_imask = cv2.bitwise_and(bgr, bgr, mask=imask)
bgrd_mask = cv2.bitwise_and(bgrd, bgrd, mask=mask)
bgr_new = cv2.add(bgr_imask, bgrd_mask)

# blur alpha channel
ab = cv2.GaussianBlur(ae, (0,0), sigmaX=3, sigmaY=3, borderType = cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)

# stretch values to 0
aa = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(ab, in_range=(200,255), out_range=(0,255))

# replace alpha channel in bgr_new with new alpha channel
out = bgr_new.copy()
out = cv2.cvtColor(out, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
out[:, :, 3] = aa

# save output
cv2.imwrite('bg_removed_antialias.png', out)

# Display various images to see the steps
cv2.imshow('BGR', bgr)
cv2.imshow('Alpha', a)
cv2.imshow('AE', ae)
cv2.imshow('AB', ab)
cv2.imshow('AA', aa)
cv2.imshow('Outline Mask', omask)
cv2.imshow('Blue Mask', bmask)
cv2.imshow('MASK', mask)
cv2.imshow('IMASK', imask)
cv2.imshow('BGR_IMASK', bgr_imask)
cv2.imshow('BGRD_MASK', bgrd_mask)
cv2.imshow('BGR_NEW', bgr_new)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I need a general-purpose algorithm which works on any background not just blue.

Comment: Use the same method, but first find the most frequent color for the background. Otherwise, see http://remove.bg, which uses AI to remove the background.