# cv2.warpPerspective produces Black dotted edges

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to implement the Pikachu image on the hoarding board using warpPerspective transformation. The output doesn't have smooth edges it has dotted points instead.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("base_img.jpg")


h_base, w_base = image.shape[0], image.shape[1]

white_subject =  np.ones((480,640,3),dtype="uint8")*255
h_white, w_white = white_subject.shape[:2]

subject = cv2.imread('subject.jpg')


h_sub, w_sub = subject.shape[:2]

pts2 = np.float32([[109,186],[455,67],[480,248],[90,349]])
pts3 = np.float32([[0, 0], [w_white, 0], [w_white, h_white], [0, h_white]])

transformation_matrix_white = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts3, pts2)
mask = cv2.warpPerspective(white_subject, transformation_matrix_white, (w_base, h_base)) 
image[mask==255] = 0

pts3 = np.float32([[0, 0], [w_sub, 0], [w_sub, h_sub], [0, h_sub]])
transformation_matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts3, pts2)
warped_image = cv2.warpPerspective(subject, transformation_matrix, (w_base, h_base))
```

Hoarding board image

[image]

Pikachu Image

[image]

Output Image

[image]

Pattern Image

[image]

Output Image
[image]

Please help me out in getting the output without the dotted point at the edges.

Comment: I dont get how you combine the warped subject with the background. Are you just copying with the mask?

Comment: I am using the transformation_matrix_white to create the mask image. With help of mask image I have overlayed the Pikachu image on the hoarding board.

Comment: You need to anti-alias your mask by blurring the edges. See for example how I do that at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63001988/how-to-remove-background-of-images-in-python/63003020#63003020 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64208431/how-to-remove-visible-background-boundary-around-object-after-saliency-detection/64216970#64216970 using Gaussianblur and skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity()

Comment: Here what I mean with smooth edges is like the output should have edges like original image edges.

Comment: You are seeing the dotted black pixels because your background color from the warpPerspective defaults to 0. After your warpPerspective, change all black pixels to the same yellow background color of the Pikachu image

Comment: I am saying to blur the edges of the mask and use that to composite the warped Pikachu image over your background. Also change any black in the warped Pikachu image to the same yellow background color before masking.

Comment: By changing the black to yellow color may work but what if subject image have multiple colors. Like can we get more generalized solution.

Comment: That is why one blurs the mask to anti-alias the outline when compositing

Comment: Use flags=cv2.INTER_NEAREST for both: mask and subject warping so you wont have pixels blended between subject and black. This will remove the wrong colors. You wont get a smooth edge then, though. For a smooth edge you will have to use anti-aliasing and interpolation between your subject and the background

Comment: If you do not have a constant color, then use cv.BORDER_REFLECT for the borderConstant in warpPerspective. That may help alleviate the black dotted outline.

Comment: I used the both cv..BORDER_TRANSPARENT and cv.BORDER_REFLECT still the border has a black dotted outline for the second pattern.

Answer (score 7):

Here is one way to do the anti-aliased composite in Python/OpenCV. Note that I use the background color of the overlay image in the borderVal constant in warpPerspective to set the background color, since it is a constant. I also blur the mask before doing the composite.

Background Image:

[image]

Overlay Image:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure

image = cv2.imread("base_img.jpg")
h_base, w_base = image.shape[0], image.shape[1]

white_subject =  np.ones((480,640,3),dtype="uint8")*255
h_white, w_white = white_subject.shape[:2]

subject = cv2.imread('subject.jpg')
h_sub, w_sub = subject.shape[:2]

# get background color from first pixel at (0,0) and its BGR components
yellow = subject[0:1, 0:1][0][0]
blue = yellow[0]
green = yellow[1]
red = yellow[2]
print(yellow)
print(blue, green, red)

pts2 = np.float32([[109,186],[455,67],[480,248],[90,349]])
pts3 = np.float32([[0, 0], [w_white, 0], [w_white, h_white], [0, h_white]])

transformation_matrix_white = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts3, pts2)
mask = cv2.warpPerspective(white_subject, transformation_matrix_white, (w_base, h_base)) 

pts3 = np.float32([[0, 0], [w_sub, 0], [w_sub, h_sub], [0, h_sub]])
transformation_matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts3, pts2)
# do warping with borderVal = background color
warped_image = cv2.warpPerspective(subject, transformation_matrix, (w_base, h_base), borderMode = cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, borderValue=(int(blue),int(green),int(red))) 

# anti-alias mask
mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (0,0), sigmaX=2, sigmaY=2, borderType = cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
mask = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(mask, in_range=(0,128), out_range=(0,255))

# convert mask to float in range 0 to 1
mask = mask.astype(np.float64)/255

# composite warped image over base and convert back to uint8
result =  (warped_image * mask + image * (1 - mask))
result = result.clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('warped_mask.png',(255*mask).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8))
cv2.imwrite('warped_image.png',warped_image)
cv2.imwrite('warped_image_over_background.png',result)

cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("warped_image", warped_image)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Anti-aliased Warped Mask:

[image]

Warped Image:

[image]

Resulting Composite:

[image]